# Getting t msg="Container ****** failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force" in docker log when deploying with ecs

Tags: docker, containers, amazon-ecs

Recently I have observed that kind of error when I deploy my micro services on ECS:

```
time="2018-11-26T10:56:43.477751125Z" level=info msg="Container ****
failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
```

I have checked the memory available on the server and the health check timeout.
All seems correct.

`Agent: 1.21.0`

`Docker: 17.03.2-ce`

Do you have any idea?

Btw, sorry it's my first question I have probably forgotten some information.

Thanks!

Comment: have you deployed your microservice task as standalone or in service? If service can you post service event logs.

Answer (score -1):

> -t 30 would give you a grace period of 30
>
> You can also use --stop-timeout when you run the container to provide
>   a bigger default for the container itself (so you don't have to
>   remember to use a bigger timeout when running docker stop).

As quoted in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/503)